# Attempts to parse string representation of list with ast.literal_eval or json.loads do not work

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I have a list of list in a string format as:

```
arg = '[[ABC, DEF], 10.10.10.10, 12345]'
```

I like to convert it to a list of string objects as:
`['[ABC, DEF]', '10.10.10.10', '12345']`

I tried converting to a python object of list type using `ast.literal_eval(arg)` and `json.loads(arg)` but both these methods throws errors since the my "arg" consists of strings that cannot be evaluated.

Is there a simpler way to achieve this?

Comment: What are ABC, DEF in the desired output? Did you mean 'ABC', 'DEF'?

Comment: That isn't a string representation of a valid list, what is `10.10.10.10` supposed to be

Comment: For that matter, what sort of object are you expecting to get from `10.10.10.10`?

Comment: @galfisher. Not a duplicate.

Comment: Why do you have this in the first place? If this string came from code that you wrote (or a coworker, or someone you're paying a support contract to, or a partner, or generally someone you can yell at until they fix it), why not fix that code instead of trying to work around it?

Comment: More generally: `literal_eval` is not magic (despite what some answers on SO seem to imply). There's a reason it's buried in the `ast` module: because its only use is to parse Python source code literals and container displays. If what you have did not come from calling `repr` on something or copying it from a Python module source, `literal_eval` is not the answer. (And if it _did_ come from calling `repr` on something, `literal_eval` is _still_ usually not the answer; the answer is to not call `repr`, and instead call something that's actually intended as a persistence format.)

Comment: @MadPhysicist: All the elements in the list are supposed to be strings.

Answer (score 9):

This looks like stringified YAML.

```
>>> import yaml
>>> yaml.safe_load('[[ABC, DEF], 10.10.10.10, 12345]')
[['ABC', 'DEF'], '10.10.10.10', 12345]
```

[**PyYAML Documentation.**](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation)

Comment: Thanks @coldspeed. Is there a way to get the desired output without the use of yaml? The systems do not have yaml installed. So, I am trying to avoid creating a dependency for the users of my module.

Comment: @PYN No, period.

Comment: *yaml ships with python-2.7+ by default*  ..huh?

Comment: @wim I wondered why there was an installation page if it was a part of the stdlib, I'm not sure. I just took a shot in the dark... would you happen to know when it was  introduced? Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, yaml has never been in the stdlib for *any* version of Python (and likely never will be). Why do you think otherwise?